# how open link from swf

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Selenium Webdriver and i want to create test for home site. There is box with advertising in swf. I need verify, if is link functional. But i dont know, how i can open link via Selenium. I wrote this code, but it is not working. (url http://www.labmultis.info/jpecka.portal-exdrazby/index.php)

```
WebElement advertising=driver.findElement(By.id("baner2"));

Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(advertising);//3 box
builder.click();
builder.perform();
```

Can anyone advise me? I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches

```
1 - You need to get the related coordinate for each element on the swf file

2 - Click on the coordinate you get in step 1st

3 - Check current link
```

Or

```
You could use
1 - FlashSelenium
2 - Sikuli
3 - FlexMonkey
4 - FlexWebdriver class
```

Hope it helps

Comment: and how i get the related coordinate for each element on the swf file? im a beginner.